# Put (save) json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have json data:

```
{ "products": [

    {
        "productId" : 0,
        "productImg" : "../img/product-photo1.png",
        "productName" : "New Balance",
        "productNameNumber" : "(1st)",
        "productSeria" : "Ref. 2514/302",
        "productColor" : "Grey",
        "productSize" : "38",
        "productAmount" : "€32.20"
    },
    {
        "productId" : 1,
        "productImg" : "../img/product-photo2.png",
        "productName" : "New Balance",
        "productNameNumber" : "(2st)",
        "productSeria" : "Ref. 2611/502",
        "productColor" : "White",
        "productSize" : "39",
        "productAmount" : "€20.10"
    }
]}
```

I need put this data to localstorage.
I have found enough information for examlple how put a data from js object to localstorage, but how put data from json file I haven't found. Help me plese find out it.

Comment: This isn't json, this is just a javascript object

Comment: Why do you think so?

JS object look like:

var name = {}

Comment: JSON means Java Script Object Notation - it's a notation to serialize Java Script objects. Yours is just a plain old javascript object. See: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: I have associative array if i don't mistake.
But i have though that json and associative array it's very similar and difference only in syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify()` to turn your object into a string. Then save it to `localStorage`.

For example:

```
var obj = { 
    "products": [
    {
        "productId" : 0,
        "productImg" : "../img/product-photo1.png",
        "productName" : "New Balance",
        "productNameNumber" : "(1st)",
        "productSeria" : "Ref. 2514/302",
        "productColor" : "Grey",
        "productSize" : "38",
        "productAmount" : "€32.20"
    },
    {
        "productId" : 1,
        "productImg" : "../img/product-photo2.png",
        "productName" : "New Balance",
        "productNameNumber" : "(2st)",
        "productSeria" : "Ref. 2611/502",
        "productColor" : "White",
        "productSize" : "39",
        "productAmount" : "€20.10"
    }
    ]
};

localStorage.setItem('someKey', JSON.stringify(obj));

console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('someKey')));
```

Comment: Thanks I have understood, but if I have some structure for example: I want to store my date in separete folder which has name date and there is json file with data, and I want in javascript file get this json file and put data to localsorage. My structure: 
js>common.js data>data.json styles>common.css img index.html

Comment: @S.Hagvin - is that another question or did you need to include more details in THIS question; it seems this answers the question you posted here.